# Is there a way to cast an object and access its properties in the same line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am talking in the context of event handler in a C# windows forms, but I'm assuming the answer could be used anywhere in C#.

To give an example, I have a form that has many check boxes that each activate a button. The CheckedChanged event is handled by a function that is very similar for each CheckBox and it looks something like this right now:

```
private void acheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int uniquetocheckbox = 12345;

    if(acheckbox.CheckedChanged)
    {
          ThisFunction(uniquetocheckbox, true);
          AssociatedButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
          ThisFunction(uniquetocheckbox, false);
          AssociatedButton.Enabled = false;
    }  
}
```

There are a lot of these check boxes and I'm trying to cut and past the code for each and make as few changes as possible so I want to do something like this :

```
private void acheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int uniquetocheckbox = 12345;

    if((CheckBox)sender.Checked)  //CHANGE HERE
    {
          ThisFunction(uniquetocheckbox, true);
          AssociatedButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
          ThisFunction(uniquetocheckbox, false);
          AssociatedButton.Enabled = false;
    }  
}
```

This does not work. The easy work around is this :

```
private void acheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int uniquetocheckbox = 12345;
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;

    if(cb.Checked)  //CHANGE HERE
    {
          ThisFunction(uniquetocheckbox, true);
          AssociatedButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
          ThisFunction(uniquetocheckbox, false);
          AssociatedButton.Enabled = false;
    }  
}
```

But out of pure curiosity I am wondering if there is a way to do it in one line like the second example I gave. I would like to know because I think it looks better and is obviously 1 line shorter.

Comment: Doesn't `((CheckBox)sender).Checked` work?

Comment: In addition to the answers, you can make it even shorter by doing: `var isChecked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked; ThisFunction(uniquetocheckbox, isChecked); AssociatedButton.Enabled = isChecked;`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan brilliant, didn't even think about that. Will be implementing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're just missing a set of parenthesis. You want to cast to `Checkbox`, then get the properties of that:

```
if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
```

This will force the order of operations to cast first, then get the property from the cast result.

Comment: You should point out that the OPs syntax was attempting to cast the result from the `.Checked` property, to make it clear why the code didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it's possible. You just missed another set of brackets:

```
if(((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
```

However, I wouldn't do this. Why? You don't want to cast again if you want to access the `sender` as a textbox again if you did it your way.

Answer (score 2):

You can. For example:

```
object o;
o = new SomeType();
var prop = ((SomeType)o).SomeProperty;
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be this:

```
if(((CheckBox)sender).Checked)  //CHANGE HERE
```

But personally I like the way you've shown better. That way if it needs to be casted again, it's already been done.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know any C# but `((CheckBox)sender).Checked)` should work. In java the "." (member access) has higher priority than casting so putting the parenthesis like this should force the casting to happen first.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a couple of more parenthesis in your `if` statement:

```
if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
{
    ...
}
```